# derivative of norm of two matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives

I am a bit rusty on math. I need to take derivate of this form:

$$\frac{d||AW||_2^2}{dW}$$

where $A, W$ are matrices.

I recall that $|AW|^2 = (AW)(AW)^T$. However, I don't know how to solve the derivative in matrix form. Any help?

Attempt:
*Is the solution: $2(W^TWA)$?*

Comment: What is $\lVert AW \rVert_2$?

Comment: Your attempt is close, but the answer is actually $\,2A^TAW \quad$

Comment: Isn't this the Frobenius norm?

Comment: If it is Frobenious norm, then it is $2A^TAW$. However, if you mean the spectral norm, then it is really hard to do that.